# How to create a context menu from code

Tags: android

I'm getting all kinds of errors when using res/menu/menu_home.xml, and my project won't build. That's when I remembered that there was a way to create menus from java code instead of declaring it via xml. Does someone remember how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the tutorial for the [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html)?

Specifically the onCreateContextMenu() and onContextItemSelected() methods